# How to get all mails from MS exchange in Python?

Tags: python, email, exchange-server-2010

I want to view all the mails I have received on MS Exchange/OWA. Is there a way to do this using Python?

I do see few solutions in [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652549/read-ms-exchange-email-in-c-sharp)/[Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612516/retrieving-mails-from-ms-exchange-server-from-java-application).

But how may I do it in Python?
A similar question is [Connect to exchange with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288546/connect-to-exchange-mailbox-with-python), but I am not able to understand how to do it.

Comment: Did you find out a solution for this?

Comment: @ebertbm not a complete solution. You got one?

Comment: I'm still looking for one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Python EWS package I maintain (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/exchangelib) supports this. Here's a simple example:

```
from exchangelib import DELEGATE, Account, Credentials

creds = Credentials(
    username='MYWINDOMAIN\myusername', 
    password='topsecret')
account = Account(
    primary_smtp_address='john@example.com',
    credentials=creds, 
    autodiscover=True, 
    access_type=DELEGATE)

# Print first 100 inbox messages in reverse order
for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:100]:
    print(item.subject, item.body, item.attachments)
```

Comment: whyn't it's working for me, throwing error in account object creation.

Comment: There’s no way to tell without the error message or stack trace.